# Application of Stoke's Theorem

Tags: physics

$\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}$
Verify the truth of Stokes' theorem in the case when $\mathbf{v} = y\unit{i} + 2x\unit{j} + z\unit{k}$, if the path $C$ is a circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in the $xy$ plane and the surface is the plane area bounded by $C$.

I am having trouble determine what the surface is.  Is it cylinder cut by the plane formed by $\mathbf{v}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The surface in this case is the unit disk in the $xy$-plane (i.e. the part of the plane $z=0$ that satisfies $x^2+y^2\leq 1$).

Comment: Yep! That's correct.

Comment: I don't know. It explicitly says "the surface is the plane area bounded by $C$".  However, his (potential) misreading of the problem doesn't make his answer wrong -- Stokes' Theorem guarantees us that the integral will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that is protruding out of closed surface. Stokes theorem guarantees that flux through each surface will be constant depending only on the path of the closed curve.
[image]
For your particular case, unit disc, i.e. $x^2+y^2 \le 1 , z=0$, would be the best choice because it's easiest.